# Select part of sentence and display using Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
IN  NS     google-public-dns-a.google.com. ; in the domain
```

From above line, I want to extract and display words in the format of the below line.

```
NS     google-public-dns-a.google.com.
```

How can I achieve this using PowerShell? Please advise.

My Code as below

```
ForEach-Object { $recordtype += ($_ -split "  " | Select-String -SimpleMatch ("NS","SOA","A","MX")  -List ) };
```

Comment: use split(";") and then select the first value [0]

Comment: You've not shown any of your own code or any indication you've tried researching/searching for a solution. (Always include your code even if it doesn't work!) I'd recommend reading [ask] and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) as at the moment your question is missing the basics that are expected when asking a question. Your question is likely to be downvoted and closed until you include the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the RegEx replace operator `-replace`. For example  `-replace '^.*?(NS|SOA|A|MX)(.*);.*','$1$2'` would exclude characters before NS, SOA, A, and MX and after a semicolon.

```
ForEach-Object { $recordtype += ($_ -split "  " | Select-String -SimpleMatch ("NS","SOA","A","MX")  -List ) -replace '^.*?(NS|SOA|A|MX)(.*?);.*','$1$2' };
```